# How to merge arbitrarily chained overlapping time ranges

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a set of events with a start and end timestamp. There are few constraints

- event 1 may overlap with events 2, 3, 5, 99, ...
- event 1 may overlap with 2 which may overlap with 3, ...
- an event may be completely contained by another event
- an event may not overlap with any other event

Here is a quick visualization of one group over overlapping events and the desired output (`s` indicates a start, and `e` indicates an end). The data may contain multiple such "chained" overlapping time ranges, as well as time ranges with no overlaps.

```
                             _______
     __________________     |       |   ______
    |       ___________|____|___    |  |      |
    |      |    __     |    |   |   |  |      |
    |      |   |  |    |    |   |   |  |      |
    |      |   |  |    |    |   |   |  |      |
    |      |   |  |    |    |   |   |  |      |
    |______|___|__|____|____|___|___|  |______|
   s1     s2  s3 e3   e1   s4  e2  e4 s5     e5                  
     _______________________________    ______
    |                               |  |      |
    |                               |  |      |
    |                               |  |      |
    |                               |  |      |
    |                               |  |      |
    |_______________________________|  |______|
   s1                              e1 s2     e2
```

#### Helper function

Here's a quick function for making an interactive plot with `plotly` in order to visualize the events. It assumes that the input is a `pd.DataFrame` with a `Start` column and an `End` column (as obtained by a simple `pd.read_csv` based on the input below).

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

def plot_events(events):
    fig = go.Figure()

    # Add dummy to generate the datetime axis
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=pd.date_range(start=events.Start.min(), end=events.End.max()),
        y=np.zeros(events.shape[0])
    ))

    # Add time capsules
    for i, event in events.iterrows():
        fig.add_vrect(
            x0=event .Start,
            x1=event .End
        )
    return fig
```

#### Raw data (CSV)

```
,Start,End,Duration
0,2020-08-03 21:05:00+00:00,2020-08-03 21:58:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
1,2020-08-03 22:53:00+00:00,2020-08-03 23:42:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
2,2020-08-03 23:29:00+00:00,2020-08-04 00:18:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
3,2020-08-04 17:01:00+00:00,2020-08-04 17:50:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
4,2020-08-12 02:09:00+00:00,2020-08-12 03:06:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
5,2020-08-12 02:13:00+00:00,2020-08-12 03:10:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
6,2020-08-12 02:33:00+00:00,2020-08-12 03:38:00+00:00,0 days 01:05:00
7,2020-08-12 04:45:00+00:00,2020-08-12 05:38:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
8,2020-08-12 05:09:00+00:00,2020-08-12 06:14:00+00:00,0 days 01:05:00
9,2020-08-12 05:37:00+00:00,2020-08-12 06:26:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
10,2020-08-12 05:57:00+00:00,2020-08-12 06:46:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
11,2020-08-12 06:09:00+00:00,2020-08-12 07:02:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
12,2020-08-12 08:21:00+00:00,2020-08-12 09:26:00+00:00,0 days 01:05:00
13,2020-08-12 08:53:00+00:00,2020-08-12 10:14:00+00:00,0 days 01:21:00
14,2020-08-12 09:49:00+00:00,2020-08-12 10:42:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
15,2020-08-12 10:09:00+00:00,2020-08-12 10:58:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
16,2020-08-12 10:37:00+00:00,2020-08-12 11:46:00+00:00,0 days 01:09:00
17,2020-08-12 13:17:00+00:00,2020-08-12 14:06:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
18,2020-08-12 13:41:00+00:00,2020-08-12 14:30:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
19,2020-08-13 07:21:00+00:00,2020-08-13 08:18:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
20,2020-08-13 07:45:00+00:00,2020-08-13 08:46:00+00:00,0 days 01:01:00
21,2020-08-14 12:33:00+00:00,2020-08-14 13:22:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
22,2020-08-14 12:33:00+00:00,2020-08-14 13:22:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
23,2020-08-21 06:49:00+00:00,2020-08-21 07:46:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
24,2020-08-21 06:49:00+00:00,2020-08-21 07:42:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
25,2020-08-21 07:05:00+00:00,2020-08-21 07:54:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
26,2020-08-21 08:53:00+00:00,2020-08-21 09:46:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
27,2020-08-21 08:53:00+00:00,2020-08-21 10:14:00+00:00,0 days 01:21:00
28,2020-08-21 10:05:00+00:00,2020-08-21 10:54:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
29,2020-08-27 16:53:00+00:00,2020-08-27 18:02:00+00:00,0 days 01:09:00
30,2020-08-27 17:05:00+00:00,2020-08-27 18:02:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
31,2020-08-27 19:57:00+00:00,2020-08-27 20:46:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
32,2020-08-27 19:57:00+00:00,2020-08-27 20:46:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
33,2020-08-27 21:37:00+00:00,2020-08-27 22:30:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
34,2020-08-28 13:45:00+00:00,2020-08-28 14:30:00+00:00,0 days 00:45:00
35,2020-08-28 13:53:00+00:00,2020-08-28 14:38:00+00:00,0 days 00:45:00
36,2020-08-28 21:33:00+00:00,2020-08-29 04:26:00+00:00,0 days 06:53:00
37,2020-09-01 23:53:00+00:00,2020-09-02 00:46:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
38,2020-09-02 00:17:00+00:00,2020-09-02 01:50:00+00:00,0 days 01:33:00
39,2020-09-02 00:17:00+00:00,2020-09-02 01:06:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
40,2020-09-02 02:33:00+00:00,2020-09-02 04:22:00+00:00,0 days 01:49:00
41,2020-09-02 02:33:00+00:00,2020-09-02 03:34:00+00:00,0 days 01:01:00
42,2020-09-02 10:09:00+00:00,2020-09-02 11:02:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
43,2020-09-02 10:57:00+00:00,2020-09-02 11:46:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
44,2020-09-14 06:13:00+00:00,2020-09-14 07:02:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
45,2020-10-12 07:29:00+00:00,2020-10-12 08:38:00+00:00,0 days 01:09:00
46,2020-10-12 07:33:00+00:00,2020-10-12 08:26:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
47,2020-10-12 09:41:00+00:00,2020-10-12 10:30:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
48,2020-10-12 09:41:00+00:00,2020-10-12 10:58:00+00:00,0 days 01:17:00
49,2020-10-16 08:05:00+00:00,2020-10-16 08:50:00+00:00,0 days 00:45:00
50,2020-10-20 13:05:00+00:00,2020-10-20 13:50:00+00:00,0 days 00:45:00
51,2020-10-25 12:45:00+00:00,2020-10-25 13:38:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
52,2020-10-25 13:21:00+00:00,2020-10-25 14:18:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
53,2020-11-14 13:13:00+00:00,2020-11-14 14:26:00+00:00,0 days 01:13:00
54,2020-11-14 13:17:00+00:00,2020-11-14 14:26:00+00:00,0 days 01:09:00
55,2020-11-14 13:49:00+00:00,2020-11-14 14:42:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
56,2020-11-14 14:21:00+00:00,2020-11-14 16:06:00+00:00,0 days 01:45:00
57,2020-12-12 09:41:00+00:00,2020-12-12 10:46:00+00:00,0 days 01:05:00
58,2020-12-12 10:09:00+00:00,2020-12-12 10:58:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
59,2020-12-12 10:37:00+00:00,2020-12-12 11:26:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
60,2020-12-12 12:33:00+00:00,2020-12-12 13:30:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
61,2020-12-12 13:25:00+00:00,2020-12-12 14:14:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
62,2020-12-18 08:13:00+00:00,2020-12-18 09:02:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
63,2020-12-19 11:17:00+00:00,2020-12-19 12:06:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
64,2020-12-19 13:01:00+00:00,2020-12-19 13:54:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
65,2020-12-23 13:53:00+00:00,2020-12-23 14:42:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
66,2020-12-24 05:33:00+00:00,2020-12-24 06:22:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
67,2020-12-25 05:49:00+00:00,2020-12-25 06:38:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
68,2020-12-30 19:57:00+00:00,2020-12-30 20:50:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
69,2020-12-31 13:13:00+00:00,2020-12-31 14:10:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
70,2021-01-02 04:05:00+00:00,2021-01-02 04:50:00+00:00,0 days 00:45:00
71,2021-01-18 04:57:00+00:00,2021-01-18 05:42:00+00:00,0 days 00:45:00
72,2021-01-27 14:01:00+00:00,2021-01-27 15:14:00+00:00,0 days 01:13:00
73,2021-01-27 14:53:00+00:00,2021-01-27 15:42:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
74,2021-03-05 06:53:00+00:00,2021-03-05 07:50:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
75,2021-03-05 06:53:00+00:00,2021-03-05 08:06:00+00:00,0 days 01:13:00
76,2021-03-05 07:29:00+00:00,2021-03-05 08:18:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
77,2021-03-05 11:09:00+00:00,2021-03-05 11:58:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
78,2021-03-05 11:09:00+00:00,2021-03-05 12:34:00+00:00,0 days 01:25:00
79,2021-03-05 13:01:00+00:00,2021-03-05 13:50:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
80,2021-03-05 13:01:00+00:00,2021-03-05 13:50:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
81,2021-03-08 07:37:00+00:00,2021-03-08 08:26:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
82,2021-03-08 07:37:00+00:00,2021-03-08 08:50:00+00:00,0 days 01:13:00
83,2021-03-08 08:13:00+00:00,2021-03-08 09:02:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
84,2021-03-08 08:29:00+00:00,2021-03-08 09:18:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
85,2021-03-08 08:37:00+00:00,2021-03-08 09:42:00+00:00,0 days 01:05:00
86,2021-03-08 09:05:00+00:00,2021-03-08 09:58:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
87,2021-03-08 09:21:00+00:00,2021-03-08 10:10:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
88,2021-03-08 09:41:00+00:00,2021-03-08 10:30:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
89,2021-03-08 10:53:00+00:00,2021-03-08 11:42:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
90,2021-03-08 12:05:00+00:00,2021-03-08 12:54:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
91,2021-03-08 12:05:00+00:00,2021-03-08 12:54:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
92,2021-03-08 12:53:00+00:00,2021-03-08 13:42:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
93,2021-03-08 13:33:00+00:00,2021-03-08 14:22:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
94,2021-03-08 14:09:00+00:00,2021-03-08 14:58:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
95,2021-03-08 14:21:00+00:00,2021-03-08 15:10:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
96,2021-03-08 14:41:00+00:00,2021-03-08 15:34:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
97,2021-03-08 20:13:00+00:00,2021-03-08 21:02:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
98,2021-03-08 20:13:00+00:00,2021-03-08 21:10:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
99,2021-03-08 20:29:00+00:00,2021-03-08 21:54:00+00:00,0 days 01:25:00
100,2021-03-08 21:57:00+00:00,2021-03-08 23:34:00+00:00,0 days 01:37:00
101,2021-03-08 22:09:00+00:00,2021-03-08 22:58:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
102,2021-03-08 23:01:00+00:00,2021-03-08 23:50:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
103,2021-03-08 23:13:00+00:00,2021-03-08 23:58:00+00:00,0 days 00:45:00
104,2021-03-08 23:21:00+00:00,2021-03-09 00:06:00+00:00,0 days 00:45:00
105,2021-03-08 23:41:00+00:00,2021-03-09 00:30:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
106,2021-03-09 00:17:00+00:00,2021-03-09 01:06:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
107,2021-03-09 00:49:00+00:00,2021-03-09 01:38:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
108,2021-03-09 01:01:00+00:00,2021-03-09 01:58:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
109,2021-03-09 01:21:00+00:00,2021-03-09 02:10:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
110,2021-03-09 01:41:00+00:00,2021-03-09 02:42:00+00:00,0 days 01:01:00
111,2021-03-09 02:09:00+00:00,2021-03-09 03:06:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
112,2021-03-09 03:01:00+00:00,2021-03-09 03:50:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
113,2021-03-09 03:49:00+00:00,2021-03-09 04:38:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
114,2021-03-09 04:13:00+00:00,2021-03-09 05:02:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
115,2021-03-09 04:25:00+00:00,2021-03-09 05:14:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
116,2021-03-09 04:25:00+00:00,2021-03-09 05:14:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
117,2021-03-09 05:01:00+00:00,2021-03-09 05:50:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
118,2021-03-09 10:05:00+00:00,2021-03-09 10:58:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
119,2021-03-09 10:09:00+00:00,2021-03-09 11:26:00+00:00,0 days 01:17:00
120,2021-03-09 10:37:00+00:00,2021-03-09 11:42:00+00:00,0 days 01:05:00
121,2021-03-09 11:41:00+00:00,2021-03-09 12:30:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
122,2021-03-09 11:53:00+00:00,2021-03-09 12:42:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
123,2021-03-09 12:25:00+00:00,2021-03-09 13:42:00+00:00,0 days 01:17:00
124,2021-03-09 13:05:00+00:00,2021-03-09 13:58:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
125,2021-03-09 13:21:00+00:00,2021-03-09 14:10:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
126,2021-03-09 13:41:00+00:00,2021-03-09 14:38:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
127,2021-03-09 15:13:00+00:00,2021-03-09 16:30:00+00:00,0 days 01:17:00
128,2021-03-09 16:01:00+00:00,2021-03-09 17:30:00+00:00,0 days 01:29:00
129,2021-03-09 16:45:00+00:00,2021-03-09 18:30:00+00:00,0 days 01:45:00
130,2021-03-09 16:53:00+00:00,2021-03-09 17:46:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
131,2021-03-09 19:21:00+00:00,2021-03-09 20:38:00+00:00,0 days 01:17:00
132,2021-03-09 19:21:00+00:00,2021-03-09 20:18:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
133,2021-03-09 20:01:00+00:00,2021-03-09 20:54:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
134,2021-03-09 22:09:00+00:00,2021-03-09 23:18:00+00:00,0 days 01:09:00
135,2021-03-10 20:37:00+00:00,2021-03-10 21:30:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
136,2021-03-10 20:53:00+00:00,2021-03-10 21:50:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
137,2021-03-11 00:01:00+00:00,2021-03-11 00:54:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
138,2021-03-11 00:25:00+00:00,2021-03-11 01:22:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
139,2021-03-11 00:49:00+00:00,2021-03-11 01:38:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
140,2021-03-11 03:25:00+00:00,2021-03-11 04:30:00+00:00,0 days 01:05:00
141,2021-03-11 04:05:00+00:00,2021-03-11 04:58:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
142,2021-03-11 04:21:00+00:00,2021-03-11 05:06:00+00:00,0 days 00:45:00
143,2021-03-11 04:29:00+00:00,2021-03-11 05:14:00+00:00,0 days 00:45:00
144,2021-03-11 07:13:00+00:00,2021-03-11 08:10:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
145,2021-03-11 07:13:00+00:00,2021-03-11 08:14:00+00:00,0 days 01:01:00
146,2021-03-11 08:09:00+00:00,2021-03-11 08:58:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
147,2021-03-11 08:13:00+00:00,2021-03-11 09:30:00+00:00,0 days 01:17:00
148,2021-03-11 09:25:00+00:00,2021-03-11 10:14:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
149,2021-03-11 10:29:00+00:00,2021-03-11 11:34:00+00:00,0 days 01:05:00
150,2021-03-11 12:49:00+00:00,2021-03-11 13:38:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
151,2021-03-11 13:37:00+00:00,2021-03-11 14:42:00+00:00,0 days 01:05:00
152,2021-03-11 14:01:00+00:00,2021-03-11 14:50:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
153,2021-03-11 14:13:00+00:00,2021-03-11 15:06:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
154,2021-03-11 14:13:00+00:00,2021-03-11 15:02:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
155,2021-03-11 15:33:00+00:00,2021-03-11 16:30:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
156,2021-03-11 16:01:00+00:00,2021-03-11 16:54:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
157,2021-03-11 16:05:00+00:00,2021-03-11 17:06:00+00:00,0 days 01:01:00
158,2021-03-12 12:21:00+00:00,2021-03-12 13:14:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
159,2021-03-12 13:13:00+00:00,2021-03-12 14:02:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
160,2021-03-12 13:13:00+00:00,2021-03-12 14:06:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
161,2021-03-12 14:13:00+00:00,2021-03-12 15:02:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
162,2021-03-12 14:33:00+00:00,2021-03-12 15:22:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
163,2021-03-12 14:49:00+00:00,2021-03-12 15:38:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
164,2021-03-12 14:57:00+00:00,2021-03-12 15:46:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
165,2021-03-12 15:09:00+00:00,2021-03-12 15:58:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
166,2021-03-12 15:09:00+00:00,2021-03-12 15:58:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
167,2021-03-12 15:25:00+00:00,2021-03-12 16:14:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
168,2021-03-12 15:57:00+00:00,2021-03-12 16:46:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
169,2021-03-12 15:57:00+00:00,2021-03-12 16:46:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
170,2021-03-12 17:33:00+00:00,2021-03-12 18:22:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
171,2021-03-16 11:57:00+00:00,2021-03-16 12:46:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
172,2021-03-16 12:01:00+00:00,2021-03-16 12:58:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
173,2021-03-16 12:37:00+00:00,2021-03-16 13:26:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
174,2021-03-16 12:57:00+00:00,2021-03-16 13:46:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
175,2021-03-16 13:13:00+00:00,2021-03-16 14:02:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
176,2021-03-16 13:45:00+00:00,2021-03-16 14:34:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
177,2021-03-16 14:01:00+00:00,2021-03-16 14:54:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
178,2021-03-16 14:05:00+00:00,2021-03-16 14:58:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
179,2021-03-16 15:09:00+00:00,2021-03-16 15:58:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
180,2021-03-16 17:41:00+00:00,2021-03-16 18:38:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
181,2021-03-16 17:49:00+00:00,2021-03-16 18:54:00+00:00,0 days 01:05:00
182,2021-03-16 18:17:00+00:00,2021-03-16 19:14:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
183,2021-03-16 18:41:00+00:00,2021-03-16 19:30:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
184,2021-03-16 18:53:00+00:00,2021-03-16 19:58:00+00:00,0 days 01:05:00
185,2021-03-16 20:01:00+00:00,2021-03-16 20:58:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
186,2021-03-16 22:05:00+00:00,2021-03-16 22:54:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
187,2021-03-16 22:17:00+00:00,2021-03-16 23:14:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
188,2021-03-16 22:41:00+00:00,2021-03-16 23:38:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
189,2021-03-16 23:41:00+00:00,2021-03-17 00:30:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
190,2021-03-17 02:57:00+00:00,2021-03-17 03:54:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
191,2021-03-17 09:37:00+00:00,2021-03-17 10:26:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
192,2021-06-28 23:05:00+00:00,2021-06-29 00:10:00+00:00,0 days 01:05:00
193,2021-06-29 00:05:00+00:00,2021-06-29 00:50:00+00:00,0 days 00:45:00
194,2021-06-29 00:13:00+00:00,2021-06-29 00:58:00+00:00,0 days 00:45:00
195,2021-09-19 23:21:00+00:00,2021-09-20 00:10:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
196,2021-09-20 03:33:00+00:00,2021-09-20 04:22:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
197,2021-09-30 09:29:00+00:00,2021-09-30 10:18:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
198,2021-09-30 09:41:00+00:00,2021-09-30 10:30:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
199,2021-09-30 09:53:00+00:00,2021-09-30 10:46:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
200,2021-11-01 11:33:00+00:00,2021-11-01 12:22:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
201,2021-11-01 12:37:00+00:00,2021-11-01 13:50:00+00:00,0 days 01:13:00
202,2021-11-01 12:45:00+00:00,2021-11-01 13:50:00+00:00,0 days 01:05:00
203,2021-11-01 13:21:00+00:00,2021-11-01 14:38:00+00:00,0 days 01:17:00
204,2021-11-01 13:21:00+00:00,2021-11-01 14:14:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
205,2021-11-01 17:49:00+00:00,2021-11-01 18:42:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
206,2021-11-01 17:49:00+00:00,2021-11-01 18:42:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
207,2021-11-01 18:33:00+00:00,2021-11-01 19:46:00+00:00,0 days 01:13:00
208,2021-11-01 18:33:00+00:00,2021-11-01 19:22:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
209,2021-11-01 20:25:00+00:00,2021-11-01 21:26:00+00:00,0 days 01:01:00
210,2021-11-01 20:29:00+00:00,2021-11-01 21:22:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
211,2021-11-01 20:49:00+00:00,2021-11-01 21:42:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
212,2021-11-01 21:41:00+00:00,2021-11-01 22:34:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
213,2021-11-01 21:57:00+00:00,2021-11-01 22:50:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
214,2021-11-01 22:17:00+00:00,2021-11-01 23:02:00+00:00,0 days 00:45:00
215,2021-11-01 22:25:00+00:00,2021-11-01 23:10:00+00:00,0 days 00:45:00
216,2021-11-02 10:29:00+00:00,2021-11-02 11:26:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
217,2021-11-02 18:09:00+00:00,2021-11-02 19:06:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
218,2021-11-03 17:01:00+00:00,2021-11-03 17:46:00+00:00,0 days 00:45:00
219,2021-11-05 09:21:00+00:00,2021-11-05 10:26:00+00:00,0 days 01:05:00
220,2021-11-06 13:21:00+00:00,2021-11-06 14:06:00+00:00,0 days 00:45:00
221,2021-11-06 13:29:00+00:00,2021-11-06 14:14:00+00:00,0 days 00:45:00
222,2021-11-13 17:21:00+00:00,2021-11-13 18:10:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
223,2021-11-13 17:33:00+00:00,2021-11-13 18:50:00+00:00,0 days 01:17:00
224,2021-11-13 18:29:00+00:00,2021-11-13 19:26:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
225,2021-11-13 19:45:00+00:00,2021-11-13 20:54:00+00:00,0 days 01:09:00
226,2021-11-13 21:09:00+00:00,2021-11-13 22:10:00+00:00,0 days 01:01:00
227,2021-11-13 21:57:00+00:00,2021-11-13 22:58:00+00:00,0 days 01:01:00
228,2021-11-13 23:25:00+00:00,2021-11-14 00:22:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
229,2021-11-14 00:01:00+00:00,2021-11-14 00:46:00+00:00,0 days 00:45:00
230,2021-11-14 00:09:00+00:00,2021-11-14 00:54:00+00:00,0 days 00:45:00
231,2021-11-14 00:45:00+00:00,2021-11-14 01:42:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
232,2021-11-14 14:45:00+00:00,2021-11-14 15:38:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
233,2021-11-14 15:17:00+00:00,2021-11-14 16:06:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
234,2021-11-14 17:05:00+00:00,2021-11-14 17:50:00+00:00,0 days 00:45:00
235,2021-11-14 17:13:00+00:00,2021-11-14 17:58:00+00:00,0 days 00:45:00
236,2021-11-14 18:09:00+00:00,2021-11-14 19:06:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
237,2021-11-14 20:21:00+00:00,2021-11-14 21:06:00+00:00,0 days 00:45:00
238,2021-11-14 20:29:00+00:00,2021-11-14 21:14:00+00:00,0 days 00:45:00
239,2021-11-14 20:53:00+00:00,2021-11-14 21:42:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
240,2021-11-14 21:05:00+00:00,2021-11-14 21:54:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
241,2021-11-14 21:09:00+00:00,2021-11-14 22:02:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
242,2021-11-14 21:17:00+00:00,2021-11-14 22:14:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
243,2021-11-14 21:33:00+00:00,2021-11-14 22:30:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
244,2021-11-14 21:53:00+00:00,2021-11-14 22:42:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
245,2021-11-14 22:01:00+00:00,2021-11-14 22:58:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
246,2021-11-14 22:05:00+00:00,2021-11-14 22:54:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
247,2021-11-14 22:17:00+00:00,2021-11-14 23:30:00+00:00,0 days 01:13:00
248,2021-11-14 22:29:00+00:00,2021-11-14 23:26:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
249,2021-11-14 23:21:00+00:00,2021-11-15 00:14:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
250,2021-11-14 23:37:00+00:00,2021-11-15 00:30:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
251,2021-11-14 23:49:00+00:00,2021-11-15 00:46:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
252,2021-11-15 00:21:00+00:00,2021-11-15 01:14:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
253,2021-11-15 00:33:00+00:00,2021-11-15 01:34:00+00:00,0 days 01:01:00
254,2021-11-15 01:01:00+00:00,2021-11-15 01:54:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
255,2021-11-15 01:17:00+00:00,2021-11-15 02:06:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
256,2021-11-15 01:33:00+00:00,2021-11-15 02:22:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
257,2021-11-15 02:01:00+00:00,2021-11-15 02:54:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
258,2021-11-15 04:33:00+00:00,2021-11-15 05:22:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
259,2021-11-15 04:49:00+00:00,2021-11-15 05:38:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
260,2021-11-15 11:17:00+00:00,2021-11-15 12:10:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
261,2021-11-15 11:37:00+00:00,2021-11-15 12:30:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
262,2021-11-15 15:57:00+00:00,2021-11-15 16:50:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
263,2021-11-15 17:57:00+00:00,2021-11-15 18:50:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
264,2021-11-15 18:21:00+00:00,2021-11-15 19:10:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
265,2021-11-15 23:29:00+00:00,2021-11-16 00:18:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
266,2021-11-15 23:53:00+00:00,2021-11-16 00:42:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
267,2021-11-16 00:13:00+00:00,2021-11-16 01:14:00+00:00,0 days 01:01:00
268,2021-11-16 00:37:00+00:00,2021-11-16 01:34:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
269,2021-11-16 00:53:00+00:00,2021-11-16 02:22:00+00:00,0 days 01:29:00
270,2021-11-16 01:49:00+00:00,2021-11-16 02:50:00+00:00,0 days 01:01:00
271,2021-11-16 02:13:00+00:00,2021-11-16 03:02:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
272,2021-11-16 02:25:00+00:00,2021-11-16 03:14:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
273,2021-11-16 02:37:00+00:00,2021-11-16 03:30:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
274,2021-11-16 05:17:00+00:00,2021-11-16 06:14:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
275,2021-11-16 19:17:00+00:00,2021-11-16 20:22:00+00:00,0 days 01:05:00
276,2021-11-16 19:53:00+00:00,2021-11-16 20:46:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
277,2021-11-16 20:13:00+00:00,2021-11-16 21:02:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
278,2021-11-16 20:25:00+00:00,2021-11-16 21:14:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
279,2021-11-16 20:53:00+00:00,2021-11-16 21:42:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
280,2021-11-16 21:05:00+00:00,2021-11-16 21:54:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
281,2021-11-16 21:29:00+00:00,2021-11-16 22:18:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
282,2021-11-16 21:41:00+00:00,2021-11-16 22:34:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
283,2021-11-16 21:45:00+00:00,2021-11-16 22:38:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
284,2021-11-16 22:01:00+00:00,2021-11-16 23:26:00+00:00,0 days 01:25:00
285,2021-11-16 22:21:00+00:00,2021-11-16 23:14:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
286,2021-11-16 22:49:00+00:00,2021-11-16 23:46:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
287,2021-11-16 23:29:00+00:00,2021-11-17 00:18:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
288,2021-11-17 00:13:00+00:00,2021-11-17 01:06:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
289,2021-11-17 00:49:00+00:00,2021-11-17 02:06:00+00:00,0 days 01:17:00
290,2021-11-17 00:49:00+00:00,2021-11-17 01:58:00+00:00,0 days 01:09:00
291,2021-11-17 03:29:00+00:00,2021-11-17 04:22:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
292,2021-11-17 03:29:00+00:00,2021-11-17 04:30:00+00:00,0 days 01:01:00
293,2021-11-17 04:01:00+00:00,2021-11-17 04:50:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
294,2021-11-17 04:05:00+00:00,2021-11-17 04:54:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
295,2021-11-17 07:25:00+00:00,2021-11-17 08:14:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
296,2021-11-17 07:25:00+00:00,2021-11-17 08:14:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
297,2021-11-17 07:37:00+00:00,2021-11-17 08:34:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
298,2021-11-17 07:37:00+00:00,2021-11-17 08:26:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
299,2021-11-17 07:57:00+00:00,2021-11-17 08:58:00+00:00,0 days 01:01:00
300,2021-11-17 10:49:00+00:00,2021-11-17 11:50:00+00:00,0 days 01:01:00
301,2021-11-17 10:57:00+00:00,2021-11-17 11:46:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
302,2021-11-17 11:13:00+00:00,2021-11-17 12:18:00+00:00,0 days 01:05:00
303,2021-11-17 11:41:00+00:00,2021-11-17 12:30:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
304,2021-11-17 14:01:00+00:00,2021-11-17 14:50:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
305,2021-11-17 14:13:00+00:00,2021-11-17 14:58:00+00:00,0 days 00:45:00
306,2021-11-17 14:25:00+00:00,2021-11-17 15:18:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
307,2021-11-17 17:17:00+00:00,2021-11-17 18:38:00+00:00,0 days 01:21:00
308,2021-11-17 18:53:00+00:00,2021-11-17 19:42:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
309,2021-11-17 18:57:00+00:00,2021-11-17 19:54:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
310,2021-11-17 19:17:00+00:00,2021-11-17 20:10:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
311,2021-11-17 20:05:00+00:00,2021-11-17 20:54:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
312,2021-11-17 20:05:00+00:00,2021-11-17 21:10:00+00:00,0 days 01:05:00
313,2021-11-17 20:21:00+00:00,2021-11-17 21:14:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
314,2021-11-17 21:01:00+00:00,2021-11-17 21:54:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
315,2021-11-17 21:21:00+00:00,2021-11-17 22:10:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
316,2021-11-17 23:29:00+00:00,2021-11-18 01:06:00+00:00,0 days 01:37:00
317,2021-11-17 23:33:00+00:00,2021-11-18 00:22:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
318,2021-11-18 00:29:00+00:00,2021-11-18 01:18:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
319,2021-11-18 00:45:00+00:00,2021-11-18 01:34:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
320,2021-11-18 01:57:00+00:00,2021-11-18 03:54:00+00:00,0 days 01:57:00
321,2021-11-18 01:57:00+00:00,2021-11-18 02:50:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
322,2021-11-18 04:53:00+00:00,2021-11-18 05:50:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
323,2021-11-18 05:57:00+00:00,2021-11-18 06:46:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
324,2021-11-18 09:45:00+00:00,2021-11-18 10:38:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
325,2021-11-18 13:33:00+00:00,2021-11-18 14:22:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
326,2021-11-18 14:25:00+00:00,2021-11-18 15:14:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
327,2021-11-18 15:33:00+00:00,2021-11-18 16:26:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
328,2021-11-18 16:13:00+00:00,2021-11-18 17:02:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
329,2021-11-18 18:17:00+00:00,2021-11-18 19:06:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
330,2021-11-18 19:01:00+00:00,2021-11-18 19:50:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
331,2021-11-18 19:57:00+00:00,2021-11-18 20:42:00+00:00,0 days 00:45:00
332,2021-11-18 20:05:00+00:00,2021-11-18 20:50:00+00:00,0 days 00:45:00
333,2021-11-20 14:33:00+00:00,2021-11-20 15:26:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
334,2021-11-20 14:53:00+00:00,2021-11-20 15:46:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
335,2021-11-20 15:29:00+00:00,2021-11-20 16:26:00+00:00,0 days 00:57:00
336,2021-11-20 15:57:00+00:00,2021-11-20 16:58:00+00:00,0 days 01:01:00
337,2021-11-20 16:05:00+00:00,2021-11-20 16:54:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
338,2021-11-20 16:17:00+00:00,2021-11-20 17:06:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
339,2021-11-20 16:29:00+00:00,2021-11-20 17:18:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
340,2021-11-20 16:53:00+00:00,2021-11-20 17:42:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
341,2021-11-20 17:21:00+00:00,2021-11-20 18:14:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
342,2021-11-20 18:45:00+00:00,2021-11-20 20:30:00+00:00,0 days 01:45:00
343,2021-11-20 19:01:00+00:00,2021-11-20 19:50:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
344,2021-11-20 19:53:00+00:00,2021-11-20 20:42:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
345,2021-11-20 20:09:00+00:00,2021-11-20 20:58:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
346,2021-11-20 20:25:00+00:00,2021-11-20 21:14:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
347,2021-11-20 20:49:00+00:00,2021-11-20 21:38:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
348,2021-11-20 21:01:00+00:00,2021-11-20 21:50:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
349,2021-11-20 22:13:00+00:00,2021-11-20 23:02:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
350,2021-11-20 23:01:00+00:00,2021-11-20 23:50:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
351,2021-11-21 03:09:00+00:00,2021-11-21 03:58:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
352,2021-11-21 03:21:00+00:00,2021-11-21 04:14:00+00:00,0 days 00:53:00
353,2021-11-21 17:09:00+00:00,2021-11-21 17:58:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
354,2021-11-21 20:33:00+00:00,2021-11-21 21:22:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
355,2021-11-22 08:33:00+00:00,2021-11-22 09:22:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
356,2021-11-22 09:17:00+00:00,2021-11-22 10:06:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
357,2021-11-22 09:57:00+00:00,2021-11-22 10:46:00+00:00,0 days 00:49:00
```

Comment: Have you checked r-tree data structure? Related Python implementations: https://rtree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ and also: https://github.com/atksh/python_prtree

Comment: What implementation problems are impeding you? In any case, one sure way is to sort by start time, then merge with previous ranges as long as possible. Also, write tests!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use of variant of the method which I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75248420/16343464).

In summary, sort the rows by Start, then End, compute a [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html) to propagate the End. Then define the standalone intervals as those that have a start that is after the previous propagated End.

```
out = (df
   # this part is to identify the overlapping intervals
   .sort_values(by=['Start', 'End'])
   .assign(max_End=lambda d: d['End'].cummax(),
           group=lambda d: d['Start'].ge(d['max_End'].shift()).cumsum())
   # this part is to aggregate the groups
   .groupby('group').agg({'Start': 'min', 'End': 'max'})
   .assign(Duration=lambda g: g['End']-g['Start'])
)
```

Output:

```
                          Start                       End        Duration
group                                                                    
0     2020-08-03 21:05:00+00:00 2020-08-03 21:58:00+00:00 0 days 00:53:00
1     2020-08-03 22:53:00+00:00 2020-08-04 00:18:00+00:00 0 days 01:25:00
2     2020-08-04 17:01:00+00:00 2020-08-04 17:50:00+00:00 0 days 00:49:00
3     2020-08-12 02:09:00+00:00 2020-08-12 03:38:00+00:00 0 days 01:29:00
4     2020-08-12 04:45:00+00:00 2020-08-12 07:02:00+00:00 0 days 02:17:00
...                         ...                       ...             ...
115   2021-11-20 22:13:00+00:00 2021-11-20 23:50:00+00:00 0 days 01:37:00
116   2021-11-21 03:09:00+00:00 2021-11-21 04:14:00+00:00 0 days 01:05:00
117   2021-11-21 17:09:00+00:00 2021-11-21 17:58:00+00:00 0 days 00:49:00
118   2021-11-21 20:33:00+00:00 2021-11-21 21:22:00+00:00 0 days 00:49:00
119   2021-11-22 08:33:00+00:00 2021-11-22 10:46:00+00:00 0 days 02:13:00

[120 rows x 3 columns]
```

Graphical example of merged intervals (the number is the index, the color is by group):

[image]

Here you see examples of fully included intervals (e.g. 246 is contained in 245), and of how the end `cummax` is working:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Convert both columns to numpy array and pass to `merge` function, last convert to datetimes and create `Duration` column:

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/5679899/2901002
def merge(times):
    saved = list(times[0])
    for st, en in sorted([sorted(t) for t in times]):
        if st <= saved[1]:
            saved[1] = max(saved[1], en)
        else:
            yield tuple(saved)
            saved[0] = st
            saved[1] = en
    yield tuple(saved)

out = pd.DataFrame(merge(df[['Start','End']].to_numpy()), 
                   columns=['Start','End']).apply(pd.to_datetime)

out['Duration'] = out['End'].sub(out['Start'])
print (out)
                        Start                       End        Duration
0   2020-08-03 21:05:00+00:00 2020-08-03 21:58:00+00:00 0 days 00:53:00
1   2020-08-03 22:53:00+00:00 2020-08-04 00:18:00+00:00 0 days 01:25:00
2   2020-08-04 17:01:00+00:00 2020-08-04 17:50:00+00:00 0 days 00:49:00
3   2020-08-12 02:09:00+00:00 2020-08-12 03:38:00+00:00 0 days 01:29:00
4   2020-08-12 04:45:00+00:00 2020-08-12 07:02:00+00:00 0 days 02:17:00
..                        ...                       ...             ...
115 2021-11-20 22:13:00+00:00 2021-11-20 23:50:00+00:00 0 days 01:37:00
116 2021-11-21 03:09:00+00:00 2021-11-21 04:14:00+00:00 0 days 01:05:00
117 2021-11-21 17:09:00+00:00 2021-11-21 17:58:00+00:00 0 days 00:49:00
118 2021-11-21 20:33:00+00:00 2021-11-21 21:22:00+00:00 0 days 00:49:00
119 2021-11-22 08:33:00+00:00 2021-11-22 10:46:00+00:00 0 days 02:13:00

[120 rows x 3 columns]
```