# Pandas Removing Rows Based on Previous Row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a Pandas dataframe with columns first_date, label, last_date, where first_date < last_date for all rows. I would like to remove any row (let's call this row z) if first_date of row Z is in between first_date and last_date of ***ANY*** row above row z of the same label (not just the the row directly above it of the same label), how can I do it? DataFrame is as follows:

```
first_date label last_date
2023-09-11 A     2023-09-17
2023-09-11 B     2023-09-15
2023-09-20 A     2023-09-28
2023-09-17 B     2023-09-30
2023-09-30 A     2023-10-05
2023-10-03 A     2023-10-07
2023-10-05 B     2023-10-15
2023-10-19 A     2023-10-20
2023-10-10 B     2023-10-15
```

the correct output should be:

```
first_date label last_date
2023-09-11 A     2023-09-17
2023-09-11 B     2023-09-15
2023-09-20 A     2023-09-28
2023-09-17 B     2023-09-30
2023-09-30 A     2023-10-05
2023-10-05 B     2023-10-15
2023-10-19 A     2023-10-20
```

where removed rows are:

```
2023-10-03 A     2023-10-07
2023-10-10 B     2023-10-15
```

because 2023-10-03 for label A is in between 2023-09-30 and 2023-10-05, and
2023-10-10 for label B is in between 2023-10-05 and 2023-10-15

The dataframe is huge, more than 10,000 rows, so should avoid loops as much as possible, thank you in advance!

Comment: Is there an ordering that can be asserted? Or is it effectively arbitrary (I can't see how I'd order the dataframe and it come out how it is in your initial data).

Comment: Hi @MatBailie thank you for pointing out the error for the last row, I have edited it.

Comment: @MatBailieorder is arbitrary, could perhaps sort by label and first_date

Comment: If you *can* sort like that, isn't the overlapping row *always* the row immediately following?  *(Can you show a scenario where you sort the dataframe and the overlapping row be anywhere else?)*

Comment: @MatBailie guess you are right. however if there's a scenario where there are 3 rows for label A where the first_date are 2023-10-15, 2023-10-16, 2023-10-17, and last_dates are 2023-10-20 for all 3 rows, I will want to keep the row with 2023-10-15 and drop the other 2

Comment: What if you have (for the same labels) a sequence of rows; `1 -> 3` , `2 -> 5`, `4 -> 6`?  If you remove the 2nd item, do you still remove the 3rd item?

Comment: @MatBailie No, keep 1->3 and 4->6, just remove the second item

Comment: Then this ***has*** to be an iterative approach.  You can't tell what to do with any given row until you've processed ***all*** preceding rows.

Comment: Please update your question with this missing information, and I can the de-clutter the question by deleting these conversational comments.

Comment: As commented below, you can [merge intervals in a vectorized way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76506279/16343464). What exactly is expected should be clarified, but maybe using this grouping logic to deduplicate (instead of merging) could lead to what you want.

Comment: can be easily done in pandas; check my answer; however with 10K rows, not sure if your rams will handle it LOL

Comment: Given then sequence of rows `1 -> 4` , `1 -> 6` which should be kept?  Given then sequence of rows `1 -> 4` , `1 -> 6` , `5 -> 8` which should be kept?  Give then sequence of rows `1 -> 4` , `1 -> 6` , `5 -> 8` , `7 -> 9` which should be kept?  *(Clarifying against the following example, and adding to you question, would be helpful; https://trinket.io/python3/6fd6071c26 )*

Answer (score -1):

There is unfortunately no efficient way to do this **in pure pandas**.

However you can use [`janitor`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor)'s efficient [`conditional_join`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) to perform a left merge and identify matching rows, then use the right indices to drop them:

```
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor

df[['first_date', 'last_date']] = df[['first_date', 'last_date']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

drop = (df.reset_index()
          .conditional_join(df.reset_index(), 
                            ('first_date', 'first_date', '>='),
                            ('first_date', 'last_date', '<='),
                            ('label', 'label', '=='),
                            ('index', 'index', '>'),
                            how='left')
         .dropna(subset=[('right', 'index')])['left']['index'].unique()
       )

out = df.drop(drop)
```

*NB. assuming a range index here, if not, assign a range to the column `index` instead of using `reset_index`.*

Output:

```
  first_date label  last_date
0 2023-09-11     A 2023-09-17
1 2023-09-11     B 2023-09-15
2 2023-09-20     A 2023-09-28
3 2023-09-17     B 2023-09-30
4 2023-09-30     A 2023-10-05
5 2023-10-03     A 2023-10-07
6 2023-10-05     B 2023-10-15
7 2023-10-19     A 2023-10-20
8 2023-10-10     B 2023-10-15
```

Intermediate `drop`: `array([5, 8])`

Merge intermediate:

```
   left                             right                            
  index first_date label  last_date index first_date label  last_date
0     0 2023-09-11     A 2023-09-17   NaN        NaT   NaN        NaT
1     1 2023-09-11     B 2023-09-15   NaN        NaT   NaN        NaT
2     2 2023-09-20     A 2023-09-28   NaN        NaT   NaN        NaT
3     3 2023-09-17     B 2023-09-30   NaN        NaT   NaN        NaT
4     4 2023-09-30     A 2023-10-05   NaN        NaT   NaN        NaT
5     5 2023-10-03     A 2023-10-07   4.0 2023-09-30     A 2023-10-05
6     6 2023-10-05     B 2023-10-15   NaN        NaT   NaN        NaT
7     7 2023-10-19     A 2023-10-20   NaN        NaT   NaN        NaT
8     8 2023-10-10     B 2023-10-15   6.0 2023-10-05     B 2023-10-15
```

Comment: See comments on the question.  OP has confirmed that for rows `1 -> 3` , `2 -> 5`, `4 -> 6`, only the middle row should be excluded.

Comment: @MatBailie I see, then it's different than initially explained. Maybe a variation of [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76506279/16343464) could work.

Comment: it can be done :)!

Answer (score -1):

I recreated your dataFrame and tried to get your output. I think you may have missed sorting out your dataset by labels before filtering based on the condition. The condition seemed pretty straight-forward, just don't forget about bitwise not operation at the end. The output you are getting are just the inverse.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'first_date': ['2023-09-11', '2023-09-11', '2023-09-20', '2023-09-17', '2023-09-30', '2023-10-03', '2023-10-05', '2023-10-20', '2023-10-10'],
    'label': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
    'last_date': ['2023-09-17', '2023-09-15', '2023-09-28', '2023-09-30', '2023-10-05', '2023-10-07', '2023-10-15', '2023-10-19', '2023-10-15']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['first_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['first_date'])
df['last_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['last_date'])
print("Original DataFrame")
print(df)

# I guess you'were missing this part
df = df.sort_values(by=['label'])

# put your condition to check if first_date in between 
# first_date and last_date of any row above row z of the same label 

mask = []
for label, group in df.groupby('label'):
    date_filter = ~((group['first_date'] > group['first_date'].shift().fillna(pd.to_datetime('1900-01-01'))) & 
                  (group['first_date'] < group['last_date'].shift().fillna(pd.to_datetime('1900-01-01'))))
    mask.extend(date_filter.tolist())


filtered_df = df[mask]
print("\nFiltered DataFrame: ")
print(filtered_df)
```

Output:

```
Original DataFrame
  first_date label  last_date
0 2023-09-11     A 2023-09-17
1 2023-09-11     B 2023-09-15
2 2023-09-20     A 2023-09-28
3 2023-09-17     B 2023-09-30
4 2023-09-30     A 2023-10-05
5 2023-10-03     A 2023-10-07
6 2023-10-05     B 2023-10-15
7 2023-10-20     A 2023-10-19
8 2023-10-10     B 2023-10-15

Filtered DataFrame: 
  first_date label  last_date
0 2023-09-11     A 2023-09-17
2 2023-09-20     A 2023-09-28
4 2023-09-30     A 2023-10-05
7 2023-10-20     A 2023-10-19
1 2023-09-11     B 2023-09-15
3 2023-09-17     B 2023-09-30
6 2023-10-05     B 2023-10-15
```

Comment: See comments on the question.  OP has confirmed that for rows `1 -> 3` , `2 -> 5`, `4 -> 6`, only the middle row should be excluded.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I will modify my answer

Answer (score -1):

I'd sort the dataframe and then iterate over it using Apply and a function that remembers the last row processed:

- https://trinket.io/python3/43f1a6d2f4

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [
  ['2023-09-11', 'A', '2023-09-17'],
  ['2023-09-11', 'B', '2023-09-15'],
  ['2023-09-20', 'A', '2023-09-28'],
  ['2023-09-17', 'B', '2023-09-30'],
  ['2023-09-30', 'A', '2023-10-05'],
  ['2023-10-03', 'A', '2023-10-07'],
  ['2023-10-05', 'B', '2023-10-15'],
  ['2023-10-19', 'A', '2023-10-20'],
  ['2023-10-10', 'B', '2023-10-15'],
  ['2023-10-12', 'B', '2023-10-18'], # Added by me
  ['2023-10-16', 'B', '2023-10-20'], # Added by me
]

df = pd.DataFrame(
  data,
  columns = ['first_date', 'label', 'last_date'],
)

df['first_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['first_date'])
df['last_date' ] = pd.to_datetime(df['last_date' ])

print(df.dtypes)
print()

df.sort_values(['label', 'first_date', 'last_date'], inplace = True)
print(df)
print()
```

```
class Filter:
  def __init__(self):
    self._label = None
    self._first = None
    self._last  = None
  
  def _persist(self, row):
    self._label = row['label']
    self._first = row['first_date']
    self._last  = row['last_date']
  
  def validate(self, row):
    if self._label != row['label']:
      self._persist(row)
      return True
    
    if self._first <= row['first_date'] <= self._last:
      return False
    
    self._persist(row)
    return True
    

filter = Filter()

df['flag'] = df.apply(filter.validate, axis=1)

print(df)
print()
```

```
   first_date label  last_date   flag
0  2023-09-11     A 2023-09-17   True
2  2023-09-20     A 2023-09-28   True
4  2023-09-30     A 2023-10-05   True
5  2023-10-03     A 2023-10-07  False
7  2023-10-19     A 2023-10-20   True
1  2023-09-11     B 2023-09-15   True
3  2023-09-17     B 2023-09-30   True
6  2023-10-05     B 2023-10-15   True
8  2023-10-10     B 2023-10-15  False
9  2023-10-12     B 2023-10-18  False
10 2023-10-16     B 2023-10-20   True
```

Comment: last row should be False; check the statement again

Comment: @ombk : In comments on the OP, it was confirmed that given `1 -> 3` , `2 -> 5` , `4 -> 6`, only the middle row should be removed.  Based on that, the above output appears correct to me.

Comment: im saying ur last row should be deleted because 10-16 is between 12 and 18; unless the OP misexplained the assignment

Comment: are you saying that they should be deleted iteratively? so if something is marked as False first then you cant compare it to other lines?

Comment: @ombk I know what you're saying, and the OP confirmed differently in the comments.  They essentially state that because rows 8 and 9 are removed, row 10 should ***not*** be removed.  *(Yes, iteratively, I stated that in the comments on the OP.)*

Answer (score -2):

```
import numpy as np
# merge on self (highly used sql trick)
new_df = df.merge(df, on="label", how="left",  suffixes=("","_new"))
# filter similar dates (not a necessary step)
new_df = new_df[(new_df["first_date"] != new_df["first_date_new"]) ]
# flag where your conditions is true
new_df["flag"] = np.where((new_df["first_date_new"] < new_df["first_date"]) & (new_df["first_date"] < new_df["last_date_new"]), True,False )

to_drop = new_df[new_df["flag"]].copy()


to_drop["shift_first_date_new"] = to_drop["first_date"].shift(+1)
to_drop["flag"] = to_drop["flag"] & (to_drop["first_date_new"] != to_drop["shift_first_date_new"])


to_drop = to_drop[to_drop["flag"]][["first_date","label","last_date"]]
pd.concat([df,to_drop]).drop_duplicates(keep=False).sort_values("label")
#
  first_date label  last_date
0 2023-09-11     A 2023-09-17
1 2023-09-11     B 2023-09-15
2 2023-09-20     A 2023-09-28
3 2023-09-17     B 2023-09-30
4 2023-09-30     A 2023-10-05
6 2023-10-05     B 2023-10-15
7 2023-10-19     A 2023-10-20


    first_date label   last_date
0   2023-09-11     A  2023-09-17
2   2023-09-20     A  2023-09-28
4   2023-09-30     A  2023-10-05
7   2023-10-19     A  2023-10-20
1   2023-09-11     B  2023-09-15
3   2023-09-17     B  2023-09-30
6   2023-10-05     B  2023-10-15
10  2023-10-16     B  2023-10-20
```

Comment: fixed.. it works now and works on ur case

Comment: ure right i forgot to copy it; now its done

Comment: hopefully it shouldnt have an extra edge cases; if so; the OP can build up on top of whatever we provided them with; its almost there
However, 10K join, good luck with that :)

Comment: The iterative approach won't have the memory overhead, and may actually be faster at that point...

Comment: OP mentioned that way after i was invested... at the end of the day i solved the issue. now i can sleep

Comment: Doesn't correctly deal with exact matches (only one should be removed) : https://trinket.io/python3/f52b901ab4

Comment: nice edge case, add a drop_duplicates(keep="first") before you do anything;
thats not part of the exercise, thats just DQ issue that should be handled by OP lol

Comment: Still has issues if two rows have the same start date (even if the end dates are different) ; https://trinket.io/python3/39bea28fc3