# How to merge rows of pytorch matrix with same element?

Tags: python, pytorch

For example, N*2 input `matrix = torch.tensor([[1, 2], [2, 3],[4, 5]])` ,
the expected output matrix is `torch.tensor([[1, 3],[4, 5]])`, since the first and second rows share the same element 2.

How can this be achieved? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could identify the rows for which the value in 0 is different from the previous in 1 and discard the other:

```
mask = matrix[1:,0]!=matrix[:-1,1]
# tensor([False,  True])

true = torch.tensor([True])

out = torch.column_stack([matrix[torch.cat((true, mask)), 0],
                          matrix[torch.cat((mask, true)), 1],
                         ])
```

Variant:

```
mask = torch.cat((torch.tensor([True]),
                  matrix[1:,0]!=matrix[:-1,1]))
# tensor([ True, False,  True])

out = torch.column_stack([matrix[mask, 0],
                          matrix[mask.roll(-1), 1],
                         ])
```

Output:

```
tensor([[1, 3],
        [4, 5]])
```

More complex example:

```
# input             # values to keep (X)
tensor([[1, 2],     #    X   -
        [2, 3],     #    -   -
        [3, 4],     #    -   X
        [0, 0],     #    X   X
        [5, 6],     #    X   -
        [6, 9]])    #    -   X

# output
tensor([[1, 4],
        [0, 0],
        [5, 9]])
```

Comment: if the input is tensor([[1, 3],  [1, 4]]),  the above method will output both rows, instead of the expacted [3,4]

Comment: @Jemma I hadn't this logic in mind. The above code works for successive pairs of (a,b), (b, c). If you want overlapping intervals you can't do this in pure torch/numpy. I solved this problem [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76506279) (for pandas). You can consider using this approach.