# Remove overlapping rows to get the optimal no. files to load for pre-processing in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have files in Azure Blob that has overlapping timeframes and I want to load the minimum necessary files to save the resources required. The timeframes are described in the filename. It looks like this:

| row | filename | start_date | finish_date | remarks for SO quesion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | from-2023-08-21-to-2023-09-12.csv | 2023-08-21 | 2023-09-12 |  |
| 2 | from-2023-09-01-to-2023-10-19.csv | 2023-09-01 | 2023-10-19 |  |
| 3 | from-2023-07-01-to-2023-09-30.csv | 2023-07-01 | 2023-09-30 | Row 3 engulfs row 1, so remove first row from df. |
| 4 | from-2023-09-01-to-2023-10-19.csv | 2023-09-01 | 2023-10-19 |  |
| 5 | from-2023-10-01-to-2023-10-31.csv | 2023-10-01 | 2023-10-31 |  |
| 6 | from-2023-10-19-to-2023-11-30.csv | 2023-10-19 | 2023-11-30 | Combination of row 4 and row 6 engulfs row 5. Hence, remove row 5 as it is redundant. |

Each file is in several GB so I want to load only the files that are necessary without losing any data, i.e. by removing the files that could be engulfed.

Here is what I have done so far:

```py
    
    # step 1: filter less than the finish date
    required_df = files_df[files_df['finish_date'] <= self.finish_date]
    # step 2: filter greater than the start date
    required_df = required_df[required_df['start_date'] >= self.start_date]
    # step 3: Remove rows that completely engulfs previous row
    required_df = required_df.sort_values(by=['finish_date', 'start_date'], ascending=True)
    required_df['start_shifted'] = required_df['start_date'].shift(-1)
    required_df['finish_shifted'] = required_df['finish_date'].shift(-1)
    # This line fulfills the "Row 3 engulfs row 1" condition
    required_df['engulfed'] = ((required_df['finish_date'] <= required_df['finish_shifted']) 
                                & (required_df['start_date'] >= required_df['start_shifted']))
```

Assuming that the start date is July 1st 2023 and finish date is Nov 30th 2023. How do I capture the "Combination of row 4 and row 6 engulfs row 5" in pandas?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can use a variation of the method that I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75248420/16343464).

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
# Sort the DataFrame by start_date and finish_date
required_df = required_df.sort_values(by=['start_date', 'finish_date'])

# Create a new column to mark rows to be removed
required_df['to_remove'] = False

# Iterate over the rows
for i in range(len(required_df) - 1):
    current_row = required_df.iloc[i]
    next_row = required_df.iloc[i + 1]
    
    # Check if the combination of the current row and the next row engulfs another row
    if current_row['finish_date'] >= next_row['finish_date']:
        required_df.at[i + 1, 'to_remove'] = True

# Remove the rows marked for removal
required_df = required_df[~required_df['to_remove']]

# Drop the helper columns
required_df = required_df.drop(columns=['to_remove'])

print(required_df)
```

Comment: One more AI answer, please stop. You're polluting this site.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer but it didn't work as expected. It doesn't capture the "combination of row 4 and row 6 engulfs row 5" part.